# How can I get User Friendly version name of Windows like 'Windows 10 Pro' from UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, environment

I tried to find a way to get the information. 
but all I got was OSVersion information like 10.0.xxxx.0 or accessing registry information. 
and I know using registry is not allowed on Windows Store Applications.

So I tried again to have, at least, 'Windows 10' but Environment has 'Windows_NT'...
I know I can match major version 10 as Windows 10 however I just want to use data as it is (for the future case)

Pleas help me. 
thanks.

Comment: Can UWP use WMI? I've seen various solutions that go that way.

Comment: @jmcilhinney No. UWP can not use WMI... that's the problem :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Community toolkit has helpers which has a static utility class [SystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/systeminformation).

It provides an easy way to access application as well as system information like `OperatingSystem`,`OperatingSystemArchitecture` and `OperatingSystemVersion` among others which can provide the exact information that you need.

Since this toolkit is maintained and updated very well you can be sure of any cases for future releases

Comment: SystemInformation, also, doesn't give like 'Windows 10 Pro' however just 'Windows' is enough for me. Thanks.